# HTTPS API call in TCL (Centos 8)

Tags: api, rest, tcl, centos8

I'm trying to make an API call in TCL using the `rest` package, but I'm unable to make it work with HTTPS.

I've installed the `tcltls` package, but I keep getting the `can't find package tls` error.

Anyone know how to install/configure it properly?
Or is there a better way to do get/post requests with TCL?

**Edit**

As @DonalFellows suggested I've added the tls package path to the `auto_path` global and it fixed the issue for now.
However now I have the following error:

```
invalid command name "::http::formatQuery"
    while executing
"::http::formatQuery source fr target en key 123456789"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval ::http::formatQuery $query"
    (procedure "::rest::simple" line 21)
    invoked from within
"::rest::get https://eurotexte-spn9.mysystran.com:8904/profiles [list source "fr" target "en" key $apiKey]"
    ("uplevel" body line 21)
    invoked from within
"uplevel {
    catch {namespace delete ::http}

# set auto_path [linsert $::auto_path 0 /usr/lib64/tcl8.6] 
lappend ::auto_path /usr/lib64/tcl8.6
lappe..."
    (procedure "code::tcl::/web/projop//packages/intranet-cust-lexcelera/www..." line 2)
    invoked from within
"code::tcl::$__adp_stub"
    ("uplevel" body line 12)
    invoked from within
"uplevel {

        if { [file exists $__adp_stub.tcl] } {

            # ensure that data source preparation procedure exists and is up-to-date
      ..."
    (procedure "adp_prepare" line 2)
    invoked from within
"adp_prepare"
    invoked from within
"template::adp_parse $themed_template {}"
    (procedure "adp_parse_ad_conn_file" line 14)
    invoked from within
"$handler"
    ("uplevel" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"uplevel $code"
    invoked from within
"ad_try {
                $handler
            } ad_script_abort val {
                # do nothing
            }"
    invoked from within
"rp_serve_concrete_file [ad_conn file]"
    (procedure "::nsf::procs::rp_serve_abstract_file" line 60)
    invoked from within
"rp_serve_abstract_file "$root/$extra_url""
    ("uplevel" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"uplevel $code"
    invoked from within
"ad_try {
                rp_serve_abstract_file "$root/$extra_url"
                set ::tcl_url2file([ad_conn url]) [ad_conn file]
                se..."
```

What is causing the issue?

Comment: The workaround is to `lappend` the correct directory (don't know which, but it's either the directory where the `pkgIndex.tcl` for the `tcltls` package is, or its immediate parent) to the global `auto_path` variable at the start of your script. The *fix* is to make sure that the package gets installed in the right place.

Comment: @DonalFellows Thank you for your answer. The package is installed at "/usr/lib64/tcl8.6/tcltls1.7.22/". Isn't that the correct path?

Comment: I dunno (and can't easily test); that's why I didn't do an answer, just about 90% of one!

Comment: Ok the **lappend** to the global **auto_path** did help, thank you! Howevere now I'm having a problem with the http package... `invalid command name "http::formatQuery"`. It seems to be coming from the **rest.tcl** code when calling the `rest::get` method.